# Model Changes is not seen unless refreshed

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on an ember application and I have a model hook which gets data from mysql and displays in a template.What I want to ask is ,when the data changes it is not seen unless the page is refreshed , is there a way to show the changes without refreshing the page? I am using edge as my browser rn .. and I am using latest version of ember..

Answer (score 1):

Ember gives the developer a way to **keep properties dynamically updated** on a **template** by denoting them as [tracked](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.3/functions/@glimmer%2Ftracking/tracked) or [computed](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/ComputedProperty).

Defining properties as `@tracked` is usually required when you update properties through some action originating from the template, i.e. if you click a button which increments the value of count by one.

Example: 
Controller file

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

export default class exampleController extends Controller {
   @tracked count;

   @action
   increment() {
     this.count++;
   }
}
```

Template file:

```html
<button type="button" {{on "click" this.increment}}>+1</button>
<p>The count is: {{this.count}}</p>
```

---

Computed properties on the other hand, are for more advanced cases where you might want to calculate a value based off of two or more variables.

Example:
(In the context of this example cats and dogs would be a `Number`)

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default class exampleController extends Controller {
  cats = 2;
  dogs = 3;

  @computed('cats', 'dogs')
  get amountOfPets() {
   return this.cats + this.dogs;
  }
}
```

Any updates made to cats or dogs from the template would also update what `this.amountOfPets` returns when called on a template.

Ember tutorial regarding the `@tracked` decorator: [Link](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-1/interactive-components/#toc_managing-state-with-tracked-properties).

Few things worth noting is that if you're passing in a property into an Ember component, it'll be tracked automatically and you won't need to use the `@tracked` decorator. Also, any model you define from the route should be tracked as-well by default.